# np.where in a loop overwriting all the values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to recode the values in my label array so that the labels 0,1,2 correspond to the center values
1.00162877,0.74014188,1.16120161

```
import numpy as np
label=np.array([0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2])
center=np.array([[1.00162877],
   [0.74014188],
   [1.16120161]])
```

Using the np.where is not overwriting all the values in a single loop but returning 3 different arrays where only a single value is changed and not all.

```
for i in range(len(center)):
    result=np.where(label==[i], center[i], label)
    print(result)

[1.00162877 2.         1.         1.         2.         1.
 1.00162877 1.00162877 1.         2.        ]
[0.         2.         0.74014188 0.74014188 2.         0.74014188
 0.         0.         0.74014188 2.        ]
[0.         1.16120161 1.         1.         1.16120161 1.
 0.         0.         1.         1.16120161]
```

How to modify the np.where or using any other function that the outcome will look like this.

```
Expected=([1.00162877,1.16120161,0.74014188,0.74014188,1.1612016,0.74014188,
       1.00162877,1.00162877,0.74014188,1.16120161])
```

Comment: python loop basics - assigning a variable in a loop does not accumulate values. It overwrites.  `where` returns `result` but does not change anything in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a loop but I think it works:

```
center[label].ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([1.00162877, 1.16120161, 0.74014188, 0.74014188, 1.16120161,
       0.74014188, 1.00162877, 1.00162877, 0.74014188, 1.16120161])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, ravel().